# Usage of facebook login + Laravel

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel-4, authentication

Just implemented facebook login on my test site, and it seems too simple to be true?

I am using these two from GitHub

https://github.com/Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib

https://github.com/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel

To implement this I added a button:

```
{{ link_to_action('UserController@loginWithFacebook', 'Facebook Login in', $parameters = array(), $attributes = array('class' => 'btn btn-primary fb-login-btn')); }}
```

And then modifiying the example login method to authorise the user after success:

```
public function loginWithFacebook() {
    $code = Input::get( 'code' );
    $fb = OAuth::consumer( 'Facebook' );

    if ( !empty( $code ) ) {
        $token = $fb->requestAccessToken( $code );

        $result = json_decode( $fb->request( '/me' ), true );

        // ADDED SECTION
        $newUser = User::create(
            array(
                'email' => $result['email']
            )
        );
        $user = User::find($newUser->id);
        Auth::login($user);
        return Redirect::to('/');
    } else {
        $url = $fb->getAuthorizationUri();
        return Redirect::to( (string)$url );
    }
}
```

This works, which has surprised me... is this really all it takes?

The question im asking really is would this be the way its intended to be used? The response is used to create a user, then log them in after with their ID.

I only use their email, since they only need to login using the facebook button. In the future I could prompt them to add a password so they don't always have to use facebook login but the basics of this is correct?

Comment: yes that's all you need oAuth wrapper does everything for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
    // get data from input
    $code = Input::get( 'code' );

    // get fb service
    $fb = OAuth::consumer( 'Facebook' );

    // check if code is valid

    // if code is provided get user data and sign in
    if ( !empty( $code ) ) {

// This was a callback request from facebook, get the token
$token = $fb->requestAccessToken( $code );

// Send a request with it
$result = json_decode($fb->request( '/me?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,email,photos' ), true);

$message = 'Your unique facebook user id is: ' . $result['id'] . ' and your name is ' . $result['name']. $result['email'];
//echo $message. "<br/>";

//Var_dump
//display whole array().
//echo('http://graph.facebook.com/'.$result['id'].'/picture?type=large<br>');
//dd($result);


$user = \User::where("email",$result['email'])->first();

if($user!=NULL){
    $userxx = Sentry::findUserByLogin($result['email']);
    Sentry::login($userxx, false);
return Redirect::to('Beşiktaş');
}
else
    {

        $k=str_random(8);
        $user = Sentry::register(array(
                    'activated' => 1,
                    'facebook' => 1,
                    'password' => $k,
                    'email' => $result['email'],
                    'first_name' =>$result['first_name'],
                    'last_name' => $result['last_name'] ,
                    'avatar' => 'http://graph.facebook.com/'.$result['id'].'/picture?type=large',

            ));

        Sentry::login($user, false);

        return Redirect::to('Beşiktaş');
    } 




    }
    // if not ask for permission first
    else {
        // get fb authorization
        $url = $fb->getAuthorizationUri();

        // return to facebook login url
         return Redirect::to( (string)$url );
    }
```